# Как закрыть интерфейс виртуалки?

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox позволяет запустить виртуалку без интерфейса:

[image: Скриншот меню запуска]

Но если я запустил её через обычный запуск, то можно ли потом перейти в вариант без интерфейса? Закрытие окна подобного варианта не предполагает, да и в меню найти не могу.

[image: Скриншот подтверждения закрытия окна]

Answer (score 2):

Можно выполнить эту операцию в 2 шага, но возможны проблемы на втором шаге.

1. Сохранить состояние машины
   `vboxmanage controlvm the_machine savestate`
2. Запустить машину через headless (в фоновом режиме)
   `vboxheadless --startvm the_machine`

Иногда машина может не загрузиться, по разным причинам)

Comment: Интересный вариант... А без перезапуска совсем никак?

Comment: Когда я интересовался этим вопросом - было никак. Сейчас не могу сказать с полной уверенностью.

Comment: Эх.. Жаль... Что ж они так?((

Comment: такая возможность есть в VMWare